# Why C# Rx Subscribe() function doesn't work with "async" keyword?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive, subscribe

I've got this code snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Observable.Range(1, 5).Subscribe(async x => await DoTheThing(x));
    Console.WriteLine("done");
}

static async Task DoTheThing(int x)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x));
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

I hope it will loop 5 times and after each loop there'll be a line printed as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But supprisingly, this will print "done" and terminate at once. Seems that async+await didn't wait the Task.Delay and quit.

Semantics doesn't seem to have problem, so where did I get wrong about Subscribe or async, how to fix it to fulfill my request of calling asynchrous tasks from Rx?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you expect 1 to 5 to be printed over the course of 5 seconds, or 15 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not blocking, because it's well - asynchronous.
Your code generates five tasks, all running parallel, all completing at various times.

But they do not block the `Main` function.
If you just add a `Console.ReadKey()` as your last line, you'll see that your code does run in the background. It prints.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Observable.Range(1, 5).Subscribe(async x => await DoTheThing(x));
    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But suppose you want to wait until all of them were done. What then?

Of course, there's `.Wait()`, but that's blocking. Let's observe all of our tasks as observables.

We'll use C# 7's `async Main` while we're at it.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Observable.Range(1, 5)
        .Select(x => DoTheThing(x).ToObservable())
        .Merge();                

    Console.WriteLine("done");
}
```

This works exactly like you'd expect it to.